# What is the equivalent of HTML class id's in WPF?

Tags: html, wpf, xaml, styles

I have some StackPanels I wish to have the same Width. However this should not affect all StackPanels and I do not want to subclass just for this. I know that the following is possible:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"
    TargetType="TextBlock"
    x:Key="TitleText">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26"/>
</Style>

...

<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleText}"> 
    Some Text 
</TextBlock>
```

But is there a way to keep the TextBlock ignorant of its Style (like it is when the
HTML is separate from the CSS rule that applies to the element)?

I would just like to give all the relevant StackPanels the same class id, and then apply
the style to the class id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in WPF. The closest you can come to this is what you've demonstrated in your example.

However, if you want to apply a style to **all** StackPanels in the **same** root container, you can specify the Style as a resource of the root container, leaving the `x:Key` attribute out. As an example:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid x:Name="StackPanelsRoot">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                ...
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <StackPanel x:Name="SP1" ... />
        <StackPanel x:Name="SP2" ... />
        ...
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="SP3" ... />
    ...
</Grid>
```

Here, the Style will be applied to `SP1` and `SP2`, but not to `SP3`

Answer (score 2):

TargetType will automatically set the Style on all objects of that type. If you want a specific TextBlock to opt out of the style you can do it like this:

```
<TextBlock Style="{x:Null}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: Your only other option is to not set TargetType and apply the style individually to each TextBlock you want it to apply to.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly there is not, but you could create an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) to set a class and then apply a style implicitly to all textblocks but use `Triggers` on that attached property to decide which setters to apply. The downside of that is that it is still not very nice of course but also that the functionality of the style is limited, as you cannot use triggers in a substyle.